# How to plot the differences inbetween series values?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v4

So I started compute the EMA Daily ticker like this:

```
Period2  = input(15, "Ema Daily Close Period",minval=1, group = "EMA Daily Length")
src2    = input(close, "Source")
ema_daily = security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", ema(src2, Period2))
plot(ema_daily, "Close EMA",  linewidth=2, color=color.black)
```

I want to use this script at lower TF (Good Example: 1H), and my main goal is to plot the slope line below (like RSI/MACD Style) that occurs from the differences of this `ema_daily`. Can anyone show me how its done? Thanks in Advance!